# AWS command line to display cpu usage of an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line

Is it possible to capture the cpu metrics of an EC2 instance using unix AWS command line? If so, do you have an example command line?

Comment: you know EC2 CPU metrics are automatically included in cloudwatch, yeah? I mean, there's no need to capture and send them to cloudwatch?

Comment: I mean, I need to capture the values of cpu perf statistics in the command line so I can use it with an in-house monitoring tool

Comment: or if there is an AWS HTTP API, that would be awesome!

Comment: as you found, there's a CLI version and a graphical UI (which isn't great, and isn't embeddable). There's also an API. Give me a few preferred languages and I'll give you an example and links.

Comment: I use AngularJS and Javascript for frontend development